# U-blox library for Arduino

Tags: gps, arduino

I need to interface an Ethernet Arduino to a [U-blox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-blox) GPS chip. I know there are lots of library versions (GPS_UBLOX) but which one is a good place to start? One with a few bells and whistles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gps system of the APM drone project from http://www.diydrones.com contains UBLOX with optional bells and whistles.

[ArduCopter GPS Git](https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/source/browse/#git/libraries/AP_GPS)

It includes the ability to switch gps type in the future using a #define, determining the type of fix and optionally communication the data via an efficient telemetry stream. The GPS part is simple to extract the rest of it is quite complex.

You will see the UBLOX  code in the gps library. You will also find an example below the library so that you don't have to dig through the main program code to make it work.

I am not connected to the project